# Log decorator for methods

Tags: python, string, types, int, decorator

I'm trying to create a decorator which logs time when method was started, name of the method and arguments of this method.

This decorator works in some situations but I want to make it work in as much situations as possible. So I want to make it work both as a normal method and as a class method.

```
def log(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            log(func.__name__ + '; ARGS: {}'.format(','.join(str(args))))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

There are some problems:

1. It does not work for class methods. To make it work in a class I would have to put `self` as a first argument here `def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):` and here `return func(*args, **kwargs)`.
2. I want to make it work for all types of arguments (lists,strings,ints,dicts etc.). This works only for strings and ints (respectively for floats etc.)
3. The weird thing is that if I use it for example on a method which takes two integers as an arguments, it prints this to the log: `name_of_function; ARGS: (,5,,, ,6,)`

I would appreciate if you help me to solve any of these problems.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
def func_detail(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print(func.__name__)
        print(*args)
        print(kwargs)
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return func_wrapper

@func_detail
def foo(a,b,c,**kwargs):
    return 1

class Person(object):
    @func_detail
    def __init__(self,name,age,**kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.email = kwargs.get('email',None)

me = Person('taesu',24,email='me@me.com')

print(foo(1,1.1,'4',test='me'))
```

Comment: Yes, this helped a lot. Thank you!

Comment: above works on py3. you might have to tweak it a bit for [py2](https://repl.it/BFjR) <- like this